# Unable to use mysql database

Tags: mysql, database-connection, schema

I have a database `mydb`.  You can see it here:

```
SHOW DATABASES

'information_schema'
'ebdb'
'mysql'
'performance_schema'
'tmp'
'mydb'
```

And I can select explicity from it:

```
SELECT *
FROM mydb.mytable
```

However, I cannot use it as my default schema.

```
USE mydb

Error Code: 1049. Unknown database 'mydb'
```

Grants for user:

```
SHOW GRANTS for 'username'
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, TRIGGER ON `%`.* TO 'username'@'%'
```

Why is the use command not working with mydb?

Comment: Maybe a typo `use myDb` ?

Comment: I tried a bunch of different capitalizations and checked for typos.  No dice :(

Comment: Like a said before, it is maybe a typo; you are using: `USE mydb` instead of `use myDb`

Comment: myDb was a typo in the question.  Sorry!  It should have said mydb.

Comment: What is the result of `SHOW GRANTS FOR yourUser` ?

Comment: @Hackerman edited the question

Comment: if you execute this command: `mysqldump -uusername -p mydb > mydb.sql` what is the result ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102488/discussion-between-steven-wexler-and-hackerman).